# Login and Password Selenium Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, google-chrome

In chrome, if there is a login page, it would pop-up as almost alert box. Read on some thread and it can be bypassed using below

```
url = 'http://{}:{}@{}'.format(username, password, webpage)
```

This one works however if the username and/or password contains special characters, there is an error that webpage is invalid. Tried to convert to utf like as sample below:

```
!@#$% user = %21%40%23%24%25+user
^&*() password = %0D%0A%26%2A%28%29+password
```

tried to put 'r' in front of the string but still has error.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: It's working now. Used the translated version to UTF. Just in case someone stumbled across on the special characters, it should be converted to utf something like this:

```
username = "%21%40user" #stands for !@user
password = "%0D%0Apass" #stands for ^&pass
webpage = "something.url.com"

url = 'http://{}:{}@{}'.format(username, password, webpage)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: it's looks like your website use Basic Authorization, so you can use next:
"http://user:pass@someurl.com", instead of using "{"